# how to separate captitalize and non captialize words?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

i have this type string

```
str =  "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRemovable neck strapBelt loop\n                                \n                                \n                                \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"
```

want to convert into

```
Removable neck strap Belt loop
```

notice how `strap` , `Belt` is separated.

So far, i have done this

```
 str.gsub(/\n|\t/,'').strip
```

which gives me

```
 Removable neck strapBelt loop
```

but fail to split between between `strapBelt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str.gsub(/([a-z])([A-Z])/, '\1 \2').strip
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this one:

```
str = str.gsub(/(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])/, ' \\1')
```

Here It is checking whether any Capital letter `[A-Z]` is exactly after a smaller letter `[a-z]` or not(Using positive lookbehind `(?<=[a-z])`). If yes, then replace it with space and the capital word(in `\\1` as captured group) itself.